# Efficiently generating synthetic data from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, probability

Let's say I have a set of probabilities in a numpy array:

[0.25, 0.12.5, 0.125, 0.50]

And I want to generate N one-hot encoded outcomes, proportional to each probability:

[0, 0, 0, 1] should be the outcome 50% of the time
[0, 0, 1, 0] should be the outcome 12.5% of the time

and so on.

I could write something to do these one-by-one, but I need several million results so backending it with numpy would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `multinomial` distribution with `n=1`:

```
In [36]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [37]: a = np.array([0.25, 0.125, 0.125, 0.50])

In [38]: N = 10

In [39]: rng.multinomial(1, a, size=N)
Out[39]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Generate a large sample, and check the means of the columns--they should be close to `a`:

```
In [40]: N = 1000000

In [41]: x = rng.multinomial(1, a, size=N)

In [42]: x.mean(axis=0)
Out[42]: array([0.249467, 0.125005, 0.124565, 0.500963])
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the array as probabilities to choose how to set up the 1 in an array of zeros:

```
a = np.array([0.25, 0.125, 0.125, 0.50])
out = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=int)
out[np.random.choice(range(len(a)), p=a)] = 1

print(out)
```

example: `array([0, 0, 0, 1])`

###### generalization to N values

```
a = np.array([0.25, 0.125, 0.125, 0.50])
N = 10
out = np.zeros((N, len(a)), dtype=int)
out[np.arange(N), np.random.choice(range(len(a)), p=a, size=N)] = 1
```

Example:

```
[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's `random.choice` can apply probabilities.

```
import numpy as np
opts = [0.25,0.125,0.125,0.5]
outcomes = [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]
z = np.random.choice(4,size=50000,p=opts)
print(z)
z = np.take(outcomes,z,axis=0)
print(z)
```

Comment: If you have many values in opts then it's no so practical to generate outcomes ;)

Comment: Yes, our two solutions take two different approaches with their own tradeoffs.

Comment: this makes me realize I haven't shown the generalization to N